# NGinx add Retry-After header to ONLY 429 Responses

Tags: nginx

Given the following NGinx config, how would I alter it to issue a Retry-After header to **ONLY** 429 reponses?

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=ip:10m rate=5r/s;
limit_req_status 429;
limit_conn_status 429;

server {

    listen 80;

    location /api {

        limit_req zone=ip burst=12 nodelay;

        proxy_pass http://website;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is variable [`$status`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_status) that holds response status value. You could use [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive to define another variable that holds retry delay and use `add_header` directive.

```
add_header Retry-After $retry_after always;
```

`add_header` will not send header if value (second argument) is empty. And we need `always` flag, otherwise it will not set header for 429 status code.

Full example:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=ip:10m rate=5r/s;
limit_req_status 429;
limit_conn_status 429;

map $status $retry_after {
    default '';
    429 '120';
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location /api {
        limit_req zone=ip burst=12 nodelay;
        proxy_pass http://website;
        add_header Retry-After $retry_after always;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll give this a go.